# Speeding up correlation matrix calculation in R

Tags: r, correlation

I have a dataframe with 49 variables and 4M rows. I want to calculate the correlation matrix of 49 x 49. All columns are of class numeric.

Here's a sample :

```
df <- data.frame(replicate(49,sample(0:50,4000000,rep=TRUE)))
```

I used the standard `cor` function.

```
cor_matrix <- cor(df, use = "pairwise.complete.obs")
```

This is taking a really long time. I have 16GB RAM and an i5 single core 2.60Ghz.

Is there a way to make this calculation faster on my desktop?

Comment: You may check [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/bigcor-large-correlation-matrices-in-r/)

Comment: Your main problem is `use = "pairwise.complete.obs"`. On my system (tested with 12 columns) that takes five times as long as `use = "everything"`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a faster version of the cor function in the WGCNA package (used for inferring gene networks based on correlations). On my 3.1 GHz i7 w/ 16 GB of RAM it can solve the same 49 x 49 matrix about 20x faster:

```
mat <- replicate(49, as.numeric(sample(0:50,4000000,rep=TRUE)))

system.time(
    cor_matrix <- cor(mat, use = "pairwise.complete.obs")
)
user  system elapsed 
40.391   0.017  40.396 

system.time(
    cor_matrix_w <- WGCNA::cor(mat, use = "pairwise.complete.obs")
)
user  system elapsed 
1.822   0.468   2.290 

all.equal(cor_matrix, cor_matrix_w)
[1] TRUE
```

Check the helpfile for the function for details on differences between versions when your data contains more missing observations.